# A good introductory reference for Hawking radiation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, resource-recommendations, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I am looking for a good reference to study the Hawking effect in detail. Hawking's [original paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02345020) is a nightmare. I first tried [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8312) introductory paper but it skips a lot of details, Ford's [QFT notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9707062) have a section on Hawking effect but it too jumps many steps. Is there a paper or any set of notes which describe the problem in detail (especially the ray tracing argument) ?